# Renaming NSString constants

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsstring, constants

I use a lot of `NSString` constants like:

```
static NSString * const REAColorPlaybackBackgroundKey = @"REAColorPlaybackBackgroundKey";
static NSString * const REAColorPlaybackForegroundKey = @"REAColorPlaybackForegroundKey";
```

There's unnecessary duplicity and no easy way to rename them. Xcode's *Refactor* command doesn't work here and *Edit All in Scope* can't handle it either. Is there a smarter way to define `NSString` constants?

Comment: You can always use `#define`.

Comment: a workaround would be to use another IDE e.g. AppCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try something like this:

```
#define STRING_CONSTANT(PREFIX, NAME, SUFFIX) static NSString *const PREFIX ## NAME ## SUFFIX = @"" #PREFIX #NAME #SUFFIX

// usage
STRING_CONSTANT(REA, ColorPlaybackBackground, Key);
STRING_CONSTANT(REA, ColorPlaybackForeground, Key);
```

Obviously, you can make `PREFIX` and `SUFFIX` constant instead of parameters if you'd prefer.